# For looping over array nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help! I want to use a for loop over an array so that it can look for titles, I have a simple ADD TODO form input and I have made it submit and push the todos or titles of the todos,

```js
  todos.push({ title: req.body.add_todo_input, complete: false });
```

I use this line to push the the users input / the todos to the array, I then use EJS to show the result on the webpage `<%= todos.title %>`, I decided why not make a for loop that loops over the array so that I can add some conditional if statements that check to see if any of the titles inside the array are equal to the same input, and if so don't push the todos and console log this message `(" Error: TODO already exists ")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `some()` method to achieve this. `some` returns `true`, when it finds an element for which the given function returns `true`, otherwise it will return `false`.

```
 const addTodo = (todos, newItem) => {
  const isTodoPresent = todos.some((todo) => todo.title === newItem);
  if (isTodoPresent) {
    console.log(' Error: TODO already exists ');
    return todos;
  }
  return todos.concat({ title: newItem, completed: false });
};

todos = addTodo(todos, req.body.add_todo_input);
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I needed for this concept. Thanks so much! I will learn this logic as much as I can to make sure I have enough knowledge to write like this in the future without needing help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `includes()` method of Array to look for titles

```
const pets = [{ title: 'cat'}, { title: 'dog'}, { title: 'bat'}];

console.log(pets.includes(t=> t.title === 'dog'));
// expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out the todo with a title are present in an array like below

```
let todo = [{title: "abc"}, {title: "def"}]
function addTodo(title) {
  let x = todo.find(item => item.title == title)
  if (x) {
    console.log("todo already present")
  } else {
    todo.push({title: title})
  }
}
```

When you add new item into todo list then use above function

```
addTodo("abc")
```

now "abc" is already exist so it shows error in console

```
addTodo("xyz")
```

now this time "xyz" will added into todo list